# Problem with variable name 'start_time' is not defined

Tags: python

## Import threading module

import threading

## Import time module to implement sleep functionality

import time

## Import datetime to get start time, end time and elapsed time

from datetime import datetime

```
#Function to loop 100000 times
def loop_fun(name):
  for i in range(0, 10):
    time.sleep(0.0001)
  print(name)
print("Loop executed!")

#Function to execute loop_fun without multithreading
num =0
def without_thread(num):
  starting_time = datetime.now()
for i in range(0, num):
  loop_fun("Called from without_thread")
ending_time = datetime.now()
elapsed_time = (ending_time - starting_time).total_seconds()
print("\n\nTime Elapsed without_thread: "+ str(elapsed_time)+"\n\n\n\n\n")


#Function to execute loop_fun with multithreading"
def with_thread(num):
  start_time = datetime.now()
threads_lst = []
# Creating threads to call loop_fun
for i in range(0, num):
    threads_lst.append(threading.Thread(target=loop_fun, args=("Called from with_thread",)))
# Running threads
for threads_ in threads_lst:
  threads_.start()
# Waiting for completion of all threads
for threads_ in threads_lst:
  threads_.join()
end_time = datetime.now()
elapsed_time = (end_time - start_time).total_seconds()
print("\n\nTime Elapsed with_thread: "+ str(elapsed_time)+"\n\n\n\n\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  without_thread(10)
with_thread(10)
```

Comment: Can you please format your code correctly. Indentation is important in python

Answer (score 0):

1. Your indentation is messed up. Copy/paste issue or does your code look like that ?
   Missing Indentation in Python makes it hard to guess what you are trying to achieve.
   Nevertheless I tried and came up with this code working w/o errors. Does it do what you want ? I frankly don't know.

I added these lines, which got messed up by the forum I think

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import threading
```

I "fixed" indentation

```
#Function to loop 100000 times
def loop_fun(name):
  for i in range(0, 10):
    time.sleep(0.0001)
    print(name)
    print("Loop executed!")

#Function to execute loop_fun without multithreading
    num =0
def without_thread(num):
    starting_time = datetime.now()
    for i in range(0, num):
        loop_fun("Called from without_thread")
        ending_time = datetime.now()
        elapsed_time = (ending_time - starting_time).total_seconds()
        print("\n\nTime Elapsed without_thread: "+ str(elapsed_time)+"\n\n\n\n\n")


#Function to execute loop_fun with multithreading"
def with_thread(num):
    start_time = datetime.now()
    threads_lst = []
# Creating threads to call loop_fun
    for i in range(0, num):
        threads_lst.append(threading.Thread(target=loop_fun, args=("Called from with_thread",)))
# Running threads
    for threads_ in threads_lst:
        threads_.start()
# Waiting for completion of all threads
    for threads_ in threads_lst:
        threads_.join()
    end_time = datetime.now()
    elapsed_time = (end_time - start_time).total_seconds()
    print("\n\nTime Elapsed with_thread: "+ str(elapsed_time)+"\n\n\n\n\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    without_thread(10)
    with_thread(10)
```

It's printing stuff like that

```
Loop executed!
Called from without_thread
Loop executed!
Called from without_thread
Loop executed!


Time Elapsed without_thread: 6.378763
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for the indentation issue! It was like this when given to me!